# Count number of categories and listwise delete if condition not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given:

```
import pandas as pd

lis1= ('apple','orange','strawberry','strawberry','strawberry','apple','orange','orange','orange','strawberry')
lis2= ("lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review")

pd.DataFrame({'category':lis1, 'review': lis2})

     category              review
0       apple  lorem ipsum review
1      orange  lorem ipsum review
2  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
3  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
4  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
5       apple  lorem ipsum review
6      orange  lorem ipsum review
7      orange  lorem ipsum review
8      orange  lorem ipsum review
9  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
```

Need:

```
lis1= ('orange','strawberry','strawberry','strawberry','orange','orange','orange','strawberry')
lis2= ("lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review", "lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review","lorem ipsum review")

pd.DataFrame({'category':lis1, 'review': lis2})

     category              review
0      orange  lorem ipsum review
1  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
2  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
3  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
4      orange  lorem ipsum review
5      orange  lorem ipsum review
6      orange  lorem ipsum review
7  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
```

I need the code to do a count of the unique categories (nunique()) and delete the categories that only appear less than 3 times. The example shows that since apple is the only category that appears twice, a listwise delete was applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the result of `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df[df.groupby('category')['category'].transform('count').gt(2)]

     category              review
1      orange  lorem ipsum review
2  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
3  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
4  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
6      orange  lorem ipsum review
7      orange  lorem ipsum review
8      orange  lorem ipsum review
9  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
```

Another solution is `value_counts` + `map`:

```
df[df.category.map(df['category'].value_counts()).gt(2)]

     category              review
1      orange  lorem ipsum review
2  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
3  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
4  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
6      orange  lorem ipsum review
7      orange  lorem ipsum review
8      orange  lorem ipsum review
9  strawberry  lorem ipsum review
```

Comment: Could you explain what the gt2 is? I've run the code and it works! Thanks. It looks like it says: if count of category is below 2, listwise delete that category. But what does gt stand for?

Comment: @D500 "greater than"